Problem: Managing Multiple Roles for Users in a Fullstack Project
I’m working on a fullstack project where I need to handle users with multiple roles. In my current setup, I have three main roles: client, recipient (destinataire), and administrator. The challenge I'm facing is that a user can potentially have more than one role at the same time. For example, a user might be both a client and a recipient, or even hold all three roles (client, recipient, and admin) simultaneously.
Current Setup:

Database: I'm using Prisma ORM with a PostgreSQL database.
User model: Currently, my User model has a role field that is an enum with two possible values: CLIENT and ADMIN. Here's a simplified version of my User model:

model User {
  id          Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  firstName   String
  lastName    String
  email       String    @unique
  phoneNumber String    @unique
  password    String?
  role        Role      @default(CLIENT)  // Role is an enum: CLIENT or ADMIN
  createdAt   DateTime  @default(now())
  updatedAt   DateTime  @updatedAt
}

enum Role {
  CLIENT
  ADMIN
}

The Problem:
Single Role Limitation: Right now, I can only assign one role per user. However, I need to manage scenarios where a user can be both a client and a recipient (for example, someone sending a parcel and also receiving one), or they could also be an admin at the same time.
Flexibility Needed: I need a system where users can hold multiple roles simultaneously, and I need a scalable solution as the system might involve new roles in the future.
Solution I'm Considering:
Many-to-Many Relationship: Instead of having a single role field in the User model, I'm considering creating a separate Role model and establishing a many-to-many relationship between User and Role. This would allow a user to have multiple roles (like CLIENT, ADMIN, and DESTINATAIRE).
Here’s a potential solution using Prisma:
model User {
  id          Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  firstName   String
  lastName    String
  email       String    @unique
  phoneNumber String    @unique
  password    String?
  createdAt   DateTime  @default(now())
  updatedAt   DateTime  @updatedAt
  roles       Role[]    @relation("UserRoles")
}

model Role {
  id   Int    @id @default(autoincrement())
  type RoleType @db.VarChar(50) // Enum with values like CLIENT, ADMIN, DESTINATAIRE
  users User[] @relation("UserRoles")
}

model UserRole {
  userId  Int
  roleId  Int
  user   User   @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  role   Role   @relation(fields: [roleId], references: [id])
  @@id([userId, roleId]) // Composite key for the many-to-many relationship
}

enum RoleType {
  CLIENT
  ADMIN
  DESTINATAIRE
}

Questions for the Forum:

Best Practice: Is this approach (using a many-to-many relationship between User and Role) the best way to handle multiple roles in a Prisma-based application? Are there any pitfalls or better alternatives?

Role Validation: How can I efficiently validate if a user has a specific combination of roles (e.g., both CLIENT and ADMIN) in the backend when handling requests?

Performance Considerations: Are there any performance considerations I should be aware of when using many-to-many relationships with roles, especially as the system scales?

Role Management: How can I handle role transitions smoothly? For example, if a user starts as a DESTINATAIRE (recipient) and later becomes a CLIENT, what's the best way to update their roles without breaking existing functionality (such as parcel tracking)?


Any insights, recommendations, or best practices would be greatly appreciated!

When talking about users and roles in a Postgres database, the first thing that comes to my mind is to do it with Postgres users and roles (with the peculiarity that user is an alias for role in Postgres). Could you perhaps explain why you are not doing it?

Many to Many relationship is the best approach. In a modern database, this should not make any performance issues even if you have thousands of users.
However if you are sure that you have only 3 roles in the system and its not going to grow to 4 or 5, you can also follow the approach of giving a numeric value to indicate the roles similar to the chmod command in unix.  client -1, recipient - 2, administrator 4.  A total value of 7 indicates all 3 roles, 3 indicates client+receipient, 6 indicates recipent+admin, 4 indicates only admin etc.
